# Using the Spread Operator to Simplify Code

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have a field like this:

```
   const updatedForm = Object.assign({}, this.state.form)
    updatedForm[name] = value;
```

Is there a way I can use the spread operator or ES6 to further simplify this?

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508). Object rest/spread does not exist in ES6. Are you limited to ES6?

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the link! no I'm just cleaning up my code in react

Comment: I find it nonsemantic to declare a `const` that you fully intend to modify. You *can* do it, but it just doesn't look right. Why not use *let* (and save some typing)? ;-)

Comment: @RobG oh that's a good point... I'll make that update as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
const updatedForm = { ...this.state.form, [name]: value };
```

Note the square brackets around `[name]`. This is due to the use of dynamic property names in your original code - this is how you do it in a literal.

Answer (score 0):

This would have the same effect as:

```
const updatedForm = {...this.state.form}

updatedForm[name] = value
```

Which in a sense is shorter and achieves the same goal.

From @Felix Kling

```
const updatedForm = {
  ...this.state.form,
  [name]: value
}
```

So you can define the new key-value pair during the creation of your newly **spreaded** object.

In practice, I'm assuming with `React`. you could do something like:

```
class Form extends React.Component{
    state = {
        form: {
            name: "",
            age: ""
        }
    }

    handleOnChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target

        const updatedForm = {
            ...this.state.form,
            [name]: value
        }

        this.setState({
            form: updatedForm
        })
    }

    render(){
        const { form } = this.state
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input name="name" value={form.name} onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
                    <input name="age" value={form.age} onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
                </form>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

See sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-galois-ifogc

Comment: Better IMO: `const updatedForm = {...this.state.form, [name]: value};`

Comment: @FelixKling now that is some next level stuff.

Comment: `name: value` adds a key called `name`, not the value of `name` variable as key. So, it should be `[name]: value`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line using `Object.assign` too:

```
const updatedForm = Object.assign({}, this.state.form, { [name]: value })
```